# Spring's @Autowired constructor gets overriden/ignored

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have SomeStartegy interface with two implementations:

```
@Primary
@Component
public class OneStrategy implements SomeStrategy {...}
@Component
public class SecondStrategy implements SomeStrategy {...}
```

I need one of them to be used as a default (primary) implementation and the other to override the default in some cases.

So I wrote something like this:

```
public class SuperClass {
     @Autowired
     SomeStrategy strategy;
}
```

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
     @Autowired
     public SubClass(SecondStrategy secondStrategy) {
         this.strategy = secondStrategy;
     }
}
```

Injecting SubClass, I can see in debug that it's ctor is called and the assignment is done like I would expect.
However, somehow it ends up with an instance of OneStrategy instead.
What am I missing here? or am I doing this all wrong?

Comment: What is the _it_ that ends up with `OneStrategy`?

Comment: the _it_ is the injected SubClass instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field injection is made **after** constructor injection.

Use constructor injection for the superclass too, and call `super(secondStrategy)` from the subclass constructor.

Comment: Yes. What I understand is that Spring calls the SubClass constructor with a SecondStrategy instance (constructor injection), and then initializes its strategy field (declared in SuperClass), because it's annotated with Autowired (field injection). The field is thus initialized twice: once by the constructor, and once by Spring, using reflection.

Comment: Hmm makes sense. I assume there is no way of doing this with out constructors, right?

Comment: Setter injection would probably work too. But constructor injection is so much cleaner.